# Compose matrix out of several subarrays in J

Tags: arrays, j

I want to compose a 12x12 matrix named *F* out of 4 given smaller submatrices which should be located at different positions:

- array A of shape 3x6 should be from (0;0) to (2;5)
- array B of shape 4x9 should be from (3;3) to (6;11)
- array C of shape 3x3 should be from (7;0) to (9;2)
- array D of shape 2x3 should be from (10;6) to (11;8)

All other atoms are zeros. I started setting up `F =: 12 12 $ 0` but failed trying the [amend](http://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Vocabulary/curlyrt#dyadic) verb. What would be best practice for this?

My subarrays are:

`A =: 3 6 $ _1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 _1 0 0 1 0 0 0.99 0 _1 0
B =: 4 9 $ 1 0 0 1 0 0 _1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 _1 0 0 1 0 0 _1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1
C =: 3 3 $ 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1
D =:  2 3 $ 1 0 0 0 0 1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a list of coordinates from the shape of each array.

```
 c_D =: {@(;&i.)/ $ D
┌───┬───┬───┐
│0 0│0 1│0 2│
├───┼───┼───┤
│1 0│1 1│1 2│
└───┴───┴───┘
```

add the offset to the above coordinates

```
c_D =: (<10 6) + &.> c_D
```

and now use amend:

```
D c_D } F
```

You can form a gerund to  streamline this process, something along the lines of:

```
g =: 3 : '({.y) +&.> {@(;&i.)/$ >{:y'
m =: ((>@{:@[)`(g@[)`])

((0 0);A) m} F
((3 3);B) m} F
etc.
```

Answer (score 3):

A slightly different approach that could work if the components have consistent shapes involves padding out the component arrays and then assembling the 12X12 array.

```
  12{."1. A     NB. Pad 0's to the right
_1 1    0 0  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0   _1 0  0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0.99 0 _1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
   _12{."1 B    NB. Pad 0's to the left
0 0 0 1 0 0 1  0 0 _1  0 0
0 0 0 0 1 0 0  0 0  0 _1 0
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 _1 0  0  0 0
0 0 0 1 0 1 1  0 1  1  0 1
   12{."1. C
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
   _12{."1 [ 6 {."1 D   NB. extra {. required to pad both ends
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
```

Then assemble the final array

```
   (12{."1. A) , (_12 {."1 B),(12 {."1 C),_12{."1[ 6 {."1 D
_1 1    0 0  0 0 0  0 0  0  0 0
 0 0   _1 0  0 1 0  0 0  0  0 0
 0 0 0.99 0 _1 0 0  0 0  0  0 0
 0 0    0 1  0 0 1  0 0 _1  0 0
 0 0    0 0  1 0 0  0 0  0 _1 0
 0 0    0 0  1 0 0 _1 0  0  0 0
 0 0    0 1  0 1 1  0 1  1  0 1
 1 0    0 0  0 0 0  0 0  0  0 0
 0 1    0 0  0 0 0  0 0  0  0 0
 0 0    1 0  0 0 0  0 0  0  0 0
 0 0    0 0  0 0 1  0 0  0  0 0
 0 0    0 0  0 0 0  0 1  0  0 0
```